# Is there a timeout limit for AppServiceConnection?

Tags: c#, uwp

I use the Win32 Application to send data to uwp through "AppServiceConnection", if the time is more than 25 seconds or so, there will be an exception. I suspect that "AppServiceConnection" has a timeout limit, but I can not find the relevant instructions. Is there a timeout limit for AppServiceConnection?
this is my code:

```
var appService = new AppServiceConnection();
        appService.AppServiceName = AppServiceName;
        appService.PackageFamilyName = PackageFamilyName;

        var status = await appService.OpenAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Create and consume an app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)
>
> An app service that is implemented as a background task will stay alive for about 30 seconds after it receives a call unless it is called again within that time window or a deferral is taken out. If the app service is implemented in the same process as the caller, the lifetime of the app service is tied to the lifetime of the caller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.